# Ruby on Rails 4 Whenever cron job working but not sure about output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cron, sendgrid, whenever

I am newbie on Ruby on rails.
I have to implement auto-generate mail functionality with **cronjobs** using **whenever gem** and I have followed this link http://www.sitepoint.com/schedule-cron-jobs-whenever-gem/ 
What I have done--- 
1. Added `user_notifier.rb` file and set all mail actions as

```
class UserNotifier < ActionMailer::Base 
  default from: "myusername@example.com"

  def two_hour_reminder
    mail( :to => 'username@example.com' ,:subject => 'Reminder')
  end

  def mail_notification
    UserNotifier.two_hour_reminder.deliver
  end
end
```

2. Added `schedule.rb`

```
every 3.minutes do
  rake 'send_digest_email'
end
```

3. Added `scheduler.rake`

```
desc 'send digest email'
task send_digest_email: :environment do
  UserNotifier.mail_notification.deliver!
end
```

4. Added `deploy.rb`

```
require 'whenever/capistrano'

set :whenever_environment, defer { stage }
set :whenever_command, 'bundle exec whenever'
```

After this I have executed command **grep CRON /var/log/syslog** where i got following log

```
CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/username/repository && RAILS_ENV=production
 bundle exec rake send_digest_email --silent')
```

But still I'm not getting any mail in inbox.
What I´m missing?

Comment: mail_notification action get execute and sent mail after hitting the action in browser.

Answer (score 2):

In schedule.rb, replaced rake 'send_digest_email' with command 'cd /home/username/repository && RAILS_ENV=development
 bundle exec rake send_digest_email --silent'

:)